# utl file frename (mv) doesn't work - 29292

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, unix

I have a a shared sftp directory mounted

> \xx.xx.xx.xx\SFTP_AX\ /sftp/ cifs 
>   user,uid=54321,gid=54321,suid,username=user,password=pass,workgroup=application,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,rw
>   0 0

Then a PL/SQL that moves my file to another mounted directory
using UTL_FILE

Here's an example

Here how I created the directory

> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY 
>       SFTP_DIR AS 
>       '/sftp/';
>
> ```
> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SFTP_DIR TO SCHEMA1;
>
> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SFTP_DIR TO SCHEMA2;
> ```

Here ls -l /sftp and /ext/files (775)

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 oracle oinstall  4096 Mar 13 14:24 sftp
drwxrwxr-x 6 oracle oinstall  4096 Mar 13 14:40 ext/files
```

So, when I execute

```
DECLARE
  sftp_folder  VARCHAR2(50)          := 'SFTP_DIR';
  l_file_test  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'test.txt';
  external_dir VARCHAR2(50)          := 'EXTERNAL_DIR';
BEGIN
  UTL_FILE.FRENAME(sftp_folder, l_file_test, external_dir, l_file_test, true);
END;
```

I get

> 29292. 00000 -  "file rename operation failed"
>          *Cause:    A file rename attempt was refused by the operating system
>                 either because the source or destination directory does not
>                 exist or is inaccessible, or the source file isn't accessible,
>                 or the destination file exists.
>          *Action:   Verify that the source file, source directory, and destination
>                 directory exist and are accessible, and that the destination
>                 file does not already exist.

I've checked everything, the files exists, **the permissions are right (IMO)** etc

Since I can't figure out, I took a approach like this
I copy my file in ext/files (using FCOPY and it works)
then **I remove my file using FREMOVE..and guess what..this works
How this can be possible? en fact mv it's like copying than removing the file..**

So FREMOVE works but FRENAME doesn't..

Any ideas?

Thank you

EDIT** I've tested also on unix..running MV between the 2 folders and it does work

EDIT**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY 
EXTERNAL_DIR AS 
'/ext/files';


GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXTERNAL_DIR TO SCHEMA1;

GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXTERNAL_DIR TO SCHEMA2;

GRANT EXECUTE, READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXTERNAL_DIR TO SYSTEM WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

EDIT*** I've tested also FOPEN..and it works

EDIT** The mounted folder is on a WINDOWS..

Comment: Your database knows of your sftp directory as `SFTP_DIR`, but in your code you call it `sftp_folder`. Did you define that as an alias somewhere, or may that be the reason for the error? Also, does your database "know" about the target directory as well, or only the source? That may be another thing to look into.

Comment: Well, sftp_folder is just the variable..it refers to SFTP_DIR which is the Oracle Directory, check the CREATE DIRECTORY...

Comment: Err. rather "check the DECLARE section" - that's what I missed. How about the target directory - I don't see the CREATE DIRECTORY for it. That would also explain why fremove works, but frename doesn't.

Comment: 1 sec, I'll edit right now

Comment: One thing you could try (for testing) is to rename the file within the same directory (without moving it at the same time). See if that works.

Comment: And - apologies - I didn't read your entire post carefully; I see some of my questions are answered already. Since you were able to copy to the other folder, clearly that's not the issue.

Comment: Yep..I've tested also 'frenaming' pass this term ;) inside the same directory and works..(src and target directories)

Comment: The only other thing I see is no `w` permission for `other` on the target folder, but since `fcopy` worked that can't be the issue either (the application must be in the owner's group for that folder or else `fcopy` should have failed also.) I agree with you that this is odd.

Comment: I've test also with 777 but nothing..maybe because both directories are mounted?

Comment: @mathguy https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533980100346684832
seems like a impossibile situation..

Comment: Hm... the answer on AskTom doesn't seem to cover your situation. If what they say is true, you shouldn't be able to rename (move) the file in place (without changing folders) either, but you said **that** kind of rename did work for you. (It is also not clear why Oracle would do that for moving/renaming but not for copying, but it does make sense if it's a bug - bugs are not necessarily expected to behave consistently!)

Comment: @mathguy https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533982000346077363

Maybe could help you too..thank you for all support